# Jenkins: Display last console output on project page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When viewing a project in Jenkins, I'd like to see the last console output displayed on the project page.

This satisfies two needs:

- I most often just want to see what the output of the build was; clicking through to the last console output seems needlessly cumbersome
- Non-technical management can't remember how to / aren't sufficiently motivated to click through to the last console output in cases where the output is relevant to them if only they were to easily see it

I've looked for plugins that support this but can't find any.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First an easy solution: job descriptions (push 'edit description' button on the main job page) admit HREF links. Make that link your latest build console permalink (`http://[jenkins_server]/job/[job-name]/lastBuild/console`).

If even one click is too much, here's a possible solution: you can use log contents as the description of your job. You can update your job via Jenkins CLI with:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://[jenkins-server] update-job [job-name] < config.xml
```

So what you need to do is this: after your jobs run, trigger another job that will take the triggering job and console output file as parameters, substitute <description> in the job's config.xml with the contents of the console file (with proper escaping, etc.), and run the update command as above. Of course, this solution is labor-intensive and bug-prone.

Comment: Nice suggestion, I'll give the second idea a shot, not as time consuming as it might seem as it can all be nicely automated.

Comment: I meant that automation is time-consuming.

Answer (score 9):

I had this same questions myself and I ended up finding this option useful...

```
http://[jenkins-server]/job/[job-name]/[build-number|lastBuild]/logText/progressiveText?start=0
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: This no longer works in the current version of Jenkins**

Similar to malenkiy_scot's answer, you can actually embed iframes in the description.

I use:

```
<iframe src='lastBuild/consoleText' style='width: 80%; height: 500px'></iframe>
```

as my project description, and it shows the latest console text in the project description page.

Comment: How this works? I just added  the above code in description area, however it is not updating with any console text. Can you please let me know how can i show the last build link in project description/dashboard?

Comment: The latest Jenkins says the field is "escaped html" and indeed it does not render. So I too am curious if we can do this.

Comment: You're right, this doesn't work in the latest versions of Jenkins. I'll post again if I come up with a new solution.

Answer (score 2):

May be you don't need it, you can click in the status button in the left of each build, each button show console output for each build.

Of course, this feature may not be operative in all Jenkins versions.

Comment: There is no longer a status button on builds in the latest version.

Comment: @Dave There is one in v2.443 (though it's not a button, it's an image) and AFAIR there has always been such. Well, much, much prettier in the past: [_How to get the classic Jenkins build status icons back?_](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/14909/24991).

Answer (score 2):

I just created a plugin that displays console output of latest build at the project page.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/display-console-output-plugin

To use this plugin, you have to type `mvn hpi:hpi` to create a `display-console-output.hpi` file. Then upload this plugin from `http://localhost:8080/pluginManager/advanced`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply just use one of these plugins:

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Hudson+Personal+View

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Console+Column+Plugin

Comment: Neither of those plugins allow for displaying the last console output on the project page

Comment: Yes, you are right - my bad. But then again they go a step further and allow displaying last console straight from the overall view. Wouldn't it be even better for your non-technical management?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your problem is the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extra+Columns+Plugin plugin for Jenkins. After installing it you may modify your view to add a button for the console output as an additional column.

Comment: This plugin can only add console output button in the view page, not the project page.

Answer (score 0):

For a declarative pipeline, you can show a link to the console right where the progress bar shows up by adding this line at the very top of the file:

```
currentBuild.description = """<a href="${JOB_URL}lastBuild/console">Job console</a>"""
```

This depends on a plugin and a setting, both of which were already on my system:

- The [OWASP Markup Formatter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/antisamy-markup-formatter/) provides the setting `Security > Configure Global Security > Markup Formatter`, which should be set to "Safe HTML".
- The setting `Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> Jenkins URL` needs to be the URL of your Jenkins installation.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I created a Dashboard view for the project the last build log of which should be accessible quickly. I limited the view to this one project in the view's **Job Filters**. I selected *Iframe portlet* at one of top, left, right, bottom. The *Iframe source url* is `http[s]://<server>[:<port>]/job/<job name>/lastBuild/console`.