# Jenkins: How to find a link in console output and put it on build page?

Tags: jenkins

I'm looking for a way to extract a link from the Jenkins build console and put that extracted text on the build's page.

The [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) doesn't help since it adds links to the build page, but the point is to provide a direct link.

The answer to [Jenkins: Display last console output on project page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496888/jenkins-display-last-console-output-on-project-page) was useful to provide a shortcut to the console, but doesn't solve this problem either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin for this. It allows to search the console log for a RegEx expression, and updates the Job's description with that. This is visible on both: right under the build in build history, and on the build's page